# Not getting the result from the async ParallelLoopResult

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When I try to get the results from the async task, I just get "System.Threading.Tasks.ParellelLoopResult" as an output. How can I get the correct result??

I would like to be able to call `Parallel.ForEach()` to do concurrent lookups, to retrieve `Customer` instance references for the `CustomerId` values passed to the `getCustomerAsync()` method. Once the call to `Parallel.ForEach()` has completed, I would like to return an array of `Customer` instances, where each element in that array corresponds to the customer ID in the input array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] id = { 1, 3, 4 };
        MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
        var result = mc.getGustomerAsync(id).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }


}

public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>()
    {
        new Customer {CustomerId = 1, Address = "My Home1", CustomerName = "Piyush1" },
        new Customer {CustomerId = 2, Address = "My Home2", CustomerName = "Piyush2" },
        new Customer {CustomerId = 3, Address = "My Home3", CustomerName = "Piyush3" },
        new Customer {CustomerId = 4, Address = "My Home4", CustomerName = "Piyush4" },
        new Customer {CustomerId = 5, Address = "My Home5", CustomerName = "Piyush5" }

    };
}

public class MethodCall
{
    public Customer getGustomer(int customerId)
    {
        CustomerList list = new CustomerList();
        return list.customerList[customerId];
    }

    public async Task<System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult> getGustomerAsync(int[] customerIds)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(customerIds, r =>
        {
            getGustomer(r);
        }));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you mixing `Task.Run` and `Parallel.ForEach`, also why do you make a new `CustomerList` every loop?

Comment: While the explanation of the output you observed is clear, much less clear is the answer to _"How can I get the correct result?"_ What _is_ in fact the "correct result" here? What result _do_ you want returned from `getGustomerAsync()`, if not the `ParallelLoopResult`? Please explain precisely what behavior it is you _do_ want.

Comment: @scott Its just a sample program, I want to send all the customerId through getCustomerAsync method and get the customerDetails in the ParallelLoopResult.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I want the List of customers in the result from getGustomerAsync() method. I want to use Parellal.Foreach.

Comment: Which "list of customers"? Every time you call `getCustomer()`, you get a new `CustomerList` object. So one call to `Parallel.ForEach()` winds up creating 5 lists in your example, plus you have the `int[] customerIds` object which could also be considered a "list" (it does implement `IList`); which list do you want? Why are you creating 5 `CustomerList` objects in the first place? Why not just create the list once _before_ calling `Parallel.ForEach()`? Would you like to return a `Customer[]` array where each element corresponds to the customer for the ID passed to `getCustomerAsync()`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, I want to return a Customer[] array where each element corresponds to the customer for the ID passed to getCustomerAsync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> I want to return a Customer[] array where each element corresponds to the customer for the ID passed to getCustomerAsync()

Okay, that makes a little more sense. Being pared down, some of the rest of the example is probably contrived and not necessarily representative of the actual real-world scenario. I am going to assume for the moment that you really do want an `async` method (i.e. you don't want to block the calling thread while `Parallel.ForEach()` is running), and that we can safely ignore the fact that you are reinstantiating the `CustomerList` every time the `getCustomer()` method is called (i.e. in reality, your code will cache a read-only list or otherwise efficiently retrieve customer information given an ID).

Then I think something like this will be better for your code:

```
public async Task<Customer[]> getGustomerAsync(int[] customerIds)
{
    Customer[] customers = new Customer[customerIds.Length];

    await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(customerIds, r =>
    {
        customers[r] = getGustomer(r);
    }));

    return customers;
}
```

Then you can call like this:

```
Customer[] customersResult = await mc.getCustomerAsync(customerIds);
```

Or if you absolutely must in a non-async method (i.e. like in your code example above, where you're calling from the `Main()` method):

```
Customer[] customersResult = mc.getCustomerAsync(customerIds).Result;
```

Comment: I just found my mistake myself, Thanks though. This is what exactly I did.